# Downloading file on Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, file, download

I'm trying to download a zip generated file but I'm getting a `FileNotFoundException`, this is the code:

```
    $zipper = new \Chumper\Zipper\Zipper;

    foreach($request->values as $id_post){
        $post = Post::find($id_post);
        $imagenes[] = public_path().'/uploads/posts/'.$post->imagen;
    }
    $nombreZip = 'test'.time().'.zip';
    $rutaZip = (public_path().'/zips/'.$nombreZip);
    $zipper->make($rutaZip)->add($imagenes);
    return (response()->download($rutaZip, 'posts.zip'));
```

I have already checked the file route that returns and the file is right there, with the same name and everything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$zipper = new \Chumper\Zipper\Zipper;

foreach($request->values as $id_post){
    $post = Post::find($id_post);
    $imagenes[] = 'public/uploads/posts/'.$post->imagen;
}
$nombreZip = 'test'.time().'.zip';
$rutaZip = (public_path().'/zips/'.$nombreZip);
$zipper->make("public/zips/{$nombreZip}")->add($imagenes);
return (response()->download($rutaZip, 'posts.zip'));
```

Comment: The same `FileNotFoundException`, and with that, it doesn't even create the file.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: `FileNotFoundException in File.php line 37:
The file "/home1/carmelaw/public_html/sites/tsmc/public/zips/test1484769608.zip" does not exist`

Comment: I meant the complete stack trace or just the first line that has a reference to your controller

Comment: Sure `at ResponseFactory->download('/home1/carmelaw/public_html/sites/tsmc/public/zips/test1484772514.zip', 'posts.zip') in PostsController.php line 56`